# Python + BeautifulSoup: How can I get full link from href attribute?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I'm putting together a web crawler for practice & learning and found some issues. My original thought process was...

1. On a given page, find all href attributes. If the href value is a valid link, go to this new link and continue
2. If the href value is a path (E.g. "/patients/patient-portal", or "/services/financial-assistance"), I would append this to the end of the current URL I'm on and continue again.

A problem arose which I hadn't realized. Some of the paths reference other resources on the website. (Picture included). Current url is "patients-visitors/advance-directives/" and the resource "services/family-medicine" actually refers to columbiabasinhospital.org/services/family-medicine". The way I have it set up would make an incorrect URL (patients-visitors/advance-directives/services/family-medicine). Mousing over the resource shows the full link. I'm wondering if there's a way to retrieve that using BeautifulSoup? Thank you!

[image]

Comment: _I would append this to the end of the current URL I'm on_ - why current url, you should add the base url - `columbiabasinhospital.org`

Answer (score 1):

Use [`urllib.parse.urljoin`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urljoin) to return the correct URL from a base URL and another, potentially relative, URL/path

```
from urllib.parse import urljoin

new_url = urljoin(current_url, href)
```

For example

```
urljoin('http://localhost/foo/bar/', '/baz/')
# Outputs 'http://localhost/baz/'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `from urllib.parse import urljoin`. But, you can write it your own self too!

Suppose that the current URL is: `http://example.com/path1/path2`

When the value of **href** attribute is sth like: `/x` you must add it to the root path, i.e. `http://example.com/x`

However, when the value of **href** attribute is sth like: `./x`, or `x` you need to add it to the whole address, i.e. `http://example.com/path1/x`

Comment: `urljoin` does both cases

Comment: @Musa I test it right now and it does not handle the second one!!!

Comment: @AlirezaKavian a link with the href `x` on a page with the URL `http://example.com/path1` will link to `http://example.com/x`. This is expected behaviour. The current URL not having a trailing slash affects the join

Comment: @IainShelvington Yeah you're right. `/x` or `x` are the same. I modified it.

Comment: @AlirezaKavian `http://example.com/path1` joined with `./x` should still be `http://example.com/x`, returning `http://example.com/path1/x` would be incorrect

Comment: @IainShelvington Yes Yes Sorry. my example sucked. I edited it and now I'm aware of my mistake :)